# Not creating any node and relations in neo4j db folder just creates the blank .db folder using java

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to create nodes and relations in neo4j demo.db folder using this code .Its just creating the blank demo.db folder .When i open this db folder in neo4j it showing zero nodes an relations. I am providing the relations.xls file.

```
public class TestAut {


    private static final File DB_PATH = new File("databases/demo.db");
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;

    private static String [] r1={"PARTNERS_JV_WITH","EXEC_JOINS","EXEC_QUITS","INVESTS_IN_TECH_IP","ACQUIRES","LAUNCHES_NEW_PRODUCT_SERVICE","LAUNCHES",
            "ACQUIRE_TALENT","DOWNSIZES_TALENT","ENTER_NEW_MARKET","DELIVERS_VALUE","OPENS_NEW_CENTER"};
    private static String [] r2={"PARTNERS_JV_WITH","EXEC_JOINS","EXEC_QUITS","INVESTS_IN_TECH_IP","ACQUIRES","LAUNCHES_NEW_PRODUCT_SERVICE","LAUNCHES",
            "ACQUIRE_TALENT","DOWNSIZES_TALENT","ENTER_NEW_MARKET","DELIVERS_VALUE","OPENS_NEW_CENTER"};
    private static Relations relations;
    public static void main(String args[]) {//throws FileNotFoundException  {
        String fileName = "relations.xls";


        Workbook workbook;

        startDb();
        relations=new Relations(r1,r2);
        System.out.println (fileName);
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(fileName)));



        br.close();

        workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(fileName));
        for(int i=0;i<workbook.getNumberOfSheets();i++) {
            Sheet sheet=workbook.getSheet(i);
            for(int j=0;j<sheet.getRows();j++)  {
                Cell cell[]=sheet.getRow(j);
                for(int k=0;k<cell.length;k++)
                    System.out.print(cell[k].getContents()+" ");
                System.out.print("\n");
                createNodesAndRelationship(cell[0].getContents(),cell[1].getContents(),
                        cell[2].getContents(),cell[3].getContents(),
                        cell[4].getContents(),cell[5].getContents(),cell[6].getContents(),cell[7].getContents());
            }
        }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BiffException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopDb();   
        System.out.println("Done!!");
        successfully.... ");
    }
    public static void startDb()    {

        graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
    }
    public static void stopDb() {
        graphDb.shutdown();

    }
    public static void createNodesAndRelationship(String subject,String subjecttype,String object,
            String objecttype,String relationship,String headline,String newslink,String date)  {

        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try 

        {

            Result result;

            result=graphDb.execute("match ("+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return "+subjecttype+".name;");

            if(result.toString().equals("empty iterator"))  {
                //Query="create (a:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return a;";
                result=graphDb.execute("create (a:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return a;");
                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }
            //Query="match ("+objecttype+"{name:\""+object+"\"}) return "+objecttype+".name;";
            result=graphDb.execute("match ("+objecttype+"{name:\""+object+"\"}) return "+objecttype+".name;");
            if(result.toString().equals("empty iterator"))  {       

                result=graphDb.execute("create (a:"+objecttype+"{name:\""+object+"\"}) return a;");
                System.out.println(result.toString());
            }

            result=graphDb.execute("match (a:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) "
                    + "match(b:"+objecttype+"{name:\""+object+"\"}) "
                    + "match (a)-[:"+relationship+"]->"
                        + "(b) return a.name,b.name;");
            if(result.toString().equals("empty iterator")&&relations.contains(relationship))    {

                result=graphDb.execute("match (a:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) "
                        + "match(b:"+objecttype+"{name:\""+object+"\"}) "
                        + "create (a)-[r:"+relationship+"{headlines:\""+
                            headline+"\",newslink:\""+newslink+ "\",date:\""+date+"\""+ "}]->(b) return r;");
                System.out.println(result.toString());

            }

            tx.success();

        }
        finally {
            tx.close();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the console output after executing this code ....

relations.xls
Southwestern Bell Corporation Company Warner Communications Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
Verizon Company Yahoo Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
AOL Company Time Warner Inc. Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
Comcast Company The Walt Disney Company Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
SBC Corporation Company Southwestern Bell Corporation Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
Comcast Company NBC Universal Company ACQUIRES TIMELINE: AT&T's Merger With Time Warner Follows Decades Of Industry Deals http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16 
sss Company sdadasfd Company ACQUIRES bndfhfdhedr http://www.npr.org/sections/thetwo-way/2016/10/22/498996253/timeline-at-ts-merger-with-time-warner-follows-decades-of-industry-deals?utm_medium=RSS&utm_campaign=technology 24/10/16

Done!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say this, but this code is really messy! Besides, we can't reproduce your results, since we don't have the data and the code is far from being a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We can't really debug for you: isolate each step, see if does anything, etc.

Here' a few tips and remarks, though.

## Testing absent results

```
if (result.toString().equals("empty iterator"))
```

Really? Please, use the API instead of a string conversion, which is never a stable interface (it's not part of any contract):

```
if (!result.hasNext())
```

## Variable or label?

Do the values of `subjecttype` and `objecttype` represent a variable name or the node of a label? The former doesn't really make sense (why should the query change when it's functionally the same), but the latter isn't properly used:

```
result=graphDb.execute("match ("+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return "+subjecttype+".name;");
```

`subjecttype` is used as a variable in the `return` clause, but looks like a label in the `match` clause, except it's missing a leading colon:

```
result=graphDb.execute("match (n:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return n.name");
```

(The final semi-colon is unnecessary)

You're actually using it correctly for the matching `create`:

```
result=graphDb.execute("create (a:"+subjecttype+"{name:\""+subject+"\"}) return a;");
```

## Query parameters

Also, your query is vulnerable to "Cypher injection" (a relative of SQL injection), if `subject` contains quotes. Use query parameters instead:

```
result = graphDb.execute("match (n:" + subjecttype + " {name:{name}}) return n.name",
        Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("name", subject));
```

It has the added benefit of making the query generic, which means it's not parsed and its execution plan is not computed for each line (only once per label).

## Use `MERGE`

You could replace your logic by simply using `MERGE` instead of `MATCH` + `CREATE`:

```
result = graphDb.execute("merge (n:" + subjecttype + " {name:{name}}) return n",
        Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap("name", subject));
```

## Power to Cypher

Your multiple queries could actually be reduced to a single one, except for the filter on `relationship` being contained in `relations`:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("subject", subject);
params.put("object", object);
params.put("headline", headline);
params.put("newslink", newslink);
params.put("date", date);
graphDb.execute(
        "MERGE (a:" + subjecttype + " {name: {subject}}) " +
        "MERGE (b:" + objecttype + " {name: {object}}) " +
        "MERGE (a)-[r:" + relationship + "]->(b) " +
        "ON CREATE SET r.headlines = {headline}, " +
        "              r.newslink = {newslink}, " +
        "              r.date = {date}",
        params);
```

With the filter, it's actually 3 queries:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("subject", subject);
params.put("object", object);
params.put("headline", headline);
params.put("newslink", newslink);
params.put("date", date);
graphDb.execute("MERGE (a:" + subjecttype + " {name: {subject}})", params);
graphDb.execute("MERGE (b:" + objecttype + " {name: {object}})", params);
if (relations.contains(relationship)) {
    graphDb.execute(
            "MATCH (a:" + subjecttype + " {name: {subject}}) " +
            "MATCH (b:" + objecttype + " {name: {object}}) " +
            "MERGE (a)-[r:" + relationship + "]->(b) " +
            "ON CREATE SET r.headlines = {headline}, " +
            "              r.newslink = {newslink}, " +
            "              r.date = {date}",
            params);
}
```

## Try-with-resources

`Transaction` is `AutoCloseable`, which means you should use a try-with-resources instead of managing it manually. Instead of

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
    // ...
} finally {
    tx.close();
}
```

just do

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.Actually the if condition is returning false all the time thats why its not creating any node and relations.I just changed my if condition and now its working fine. Thanks again for your response...

Answer (score 1):

Actually the if condition is returning false all the time thats why its not creating any node and relations.I just changed my if condition and now its working fine.

try

```
        {

            Result result;

                result =  graphDb.execute("merge (a:" + subjecttype + "{name:\"" + subject + "\"}) return a;");


        result = graphDb.execute("merge (a:" + objecttype + "{name:\"" + object + "\"}) return a;");


        result = graphDb.execute("merge (a:" + subjecttype + "{name:\"" + subject + "\"}) " + "merge(b:"
                + objecttype + "{name:\"" + object + "\"}) " + "merge (a)-[r:" + relationship + "{headlines:\""
                + headline + "\",newslink:\"" + newslink + "\",date:\"" + date + "\"" + "}]->(b) return r;");
            tx.success();
        }

        finally {
            tx.close();
        }
```